# Javascript Api Identify Raster pixel value

Tags: javascript, arcgis, raster

I have this map loaded  using the ArcGIS API

> http://ags.servirlabs.net/ArcGIS/rest/services/ReferenceNode/TRMM_30DAY/MapServer

I want to let the user click on the raster layer and display the pixel value at that specific x,y location in a pop up window. While googling I found this example

> https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/find_popup.html

explaining how to use IdentifyTask. Can I use this feature for a raster layer plus the data is already loaded do I need to make an extra request to get the values every time the user clicks on the layer?